# Force Azure to reinstall all bower dependencies

Tags: angularjs, azure, bower

## Question

#### How do I force Azure to reinstall all dependencies?

## Background

Azure was failing to deploy from source control due to an error within the bower file. Angular needed to be resolved to a certain version. I selected the wrong version, causing errors in the app. Azure deployed these changes correctly.

I found the correct version, updated the resolution on the bower file, and confirmed that everything was working ok locally after deleting the bower_components and reinstalling using `bower install`.

## Problem

Using Azure's visual studio online, I can see that the bower file has indeed updated to the correct resolution version, but it hasn't updated the bower_component version of Angular.

[image]

## Solution Attempts

1. Added dependency I didn't need, hoping that it would reinstall **all** dependencies. It only installed the new dependency.
2. Decoupled source control from GitHub, then recoupled. This worked, but I do not have access to the production site's deployment to try this.
3. Changed Angular's version to match the version of the resolution. Still maintained incorrect, previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **bower.json** add :

```
rm -rf public/bower_components/
```

just before you install the bower components.

Comment: This is a great way to get a clean install of your bower componenets